# Selecting 3 posts bodies of top reputation Users on Stackexchange-SQL

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I need a query to get results from StackExchange dataset in such a way that it returns me 100 top Reputation Users with not more than 3 posts (body of post) for each user. The Tables are like this:

Users: (id, reputation)
Posts: (id, OwnerUserId, body)

I have written the following Query:

```
SELECT top 100

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY u.Reputation DESC) AS rank, 

u.Id AS [User Link], u. Reputation, p.Body

from
      Users u
      inner join Posts p on p.OwnerUserId = u.Id 

ORDER BY
    u.Reputation DESC
```

it returns all the posts of each user, but what I want is to get only 3 posts (body) of each user. Please help!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What exactly keeps _you_ from writing the query?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP showed no attempt to solve the problem himself.

Comment: I am sorry Dan Bracuk and Rene Vogt, I am trying myself to solve this problem as you can see my query above (I have added the query in the question) and I have tried a lot of different queries but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `cross apply()`:

```
select 
   u.rank
 , u.Id as [User Link]
 , u.Reputation
 , p.Body
from (
  select top 100 *
    , row_number() over (
        order by u.Reputation desc
      ) as rank
  from Users u
  order by u.Reputation desc
  ) as u
cross apply (
  select top 3
    p.body
  from Posts p
  where p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
  ) p
order by u.Reputation desc
```

demo: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/645393/805819/

Comment: Man You are an angel! you saved my life. It works like a charm. The only thing I don't understand is that top users are, Robert Harvey, Karl Bielefeldt, Arseni, ..., but this query is showing me different top users

Comment: @SaqibIqbal You would probably need to switch the site to target the stackexchange site of your choice. There is a box inbetween the query and results that allows you to do so.